# Inputs are not responding (cn1)

Tags: codenameone

I have build a project but No inputs are responding. The textField doesn't get focus. Keyboard doesn't appear. Only buttons are working. What happened?

Comment: On which platform? Does it happen with a test case?

Comment: In android devices and simulator as well... it worked in test case but I had projects which worked fine before a month. Now all of them(textField, textArea, Picker, Checkbox etc) are not working. The interesting part is if I open the drawer menu 2-3 times, then it starts working (P.S clicking the menu icon doesn't work bt sliding the menu couple of times works & then everything works)

Comment: That sounds like an issue we fixed in git but I'm not 100% sure about that. It should be up in the Friday update

Comment: I just wanted to comment that I am also experiencing this same behavior on iOS and simulator.  With the simulator I can still click into a TextField and type, but my cursor does not change.  iOS debug builds do not display the keyboard when pressing into a field.  Opening the side menu and closing seems to put things back to "normal".

Comment: This might be related to this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52954030/event-handling-anomaly

Comment: @Tommo exactly same here